# How to center viewport at center of the sphere

Tags: android, opengl-es, panoramas

I want to create panorama view with opengl in Android. Is it possible using spherical view and centering viewpoint at the sphere center to show bounded image on screen? Will this be a good aproach? I haven't used opengl but want to achive this effect in Android. Am I going in right direction? Any pointers for this will be great help.

Thanks in advance.